# SQL Server Using a condition in a Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, sql-update

I have a field of data which consists of account numbers like this

```
16530907-00
16530907-0001

16589553-00
16589553-00
```

I want to select everything to the right of the hyphen then if the Length of that substring is >2 I want to Update that field and set it to itself minus the two extra digits on the right.

I am practicing with a select statement

```
Select SUBSTRING(Account, CHARINDEX('-'), Account)+1, LEN(Account) as test
FROM Documents
WHERE SubmissionID=45925 and LEN(test)>2
```

This does not work. What I really want to do is create an update statement that tests the characters to the right of the hyphen if there are more than 2 characters then truncate any extra characters .

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I need to learn how to spell character

Comment: You're able to edit your question. Also, why not post an example of the input and output you're expecting; what you describe isn't very clear.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Some of the proposed solutions will only work with 2005 or higher

Comment: @Abe "some"? you mean "one" :)

Comment: I am using SQL server 2005 an example of the input would be two account numbers which are identical except for two extra digits ex:1234-00 and 1234-0099 I want to look at everything to the right of the hyphen and strip of the two extra digits and make the numbers the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their comments and suggestions. I used some of what was here to devise a solution that I think will work well for me. Here it is.

```
Update Documents
Set Acount=LEFT(Account,Len(Account)-2)
WHERE Submid=41632 AND Account LIKE '%-____'
```

(Thanks to @Richard for that last bit!')

Comment: I see that you're new here (new is relative). It's great to see your final answer! We normally also tick an answer to accept it and it sort-of "closes" the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select SUBSTRING(Account,0,CHARINDEX('-',Account)+3) as UpdatedAccount, Account
FROM Documents 
WHERE SubmissionID=45925 
and LEN(SUBSTRING(Account, CHARINDEX('-',Account)+1,LEN(Account)) ) > 2
AND CHARINDEX('-',Account) > 0
```

It's ugly but appears do do what you want

Your update would look like this:

```
UPDATE Documents
SET Account = SUBSTRING(Account,0,CHARINDEX('-',Account)+3)
WHERE SubmissionID=45925 
and LEN(SUBSTRING(Account, CHARINDEX('-',Account)+1,LEN(Account)) ) > 2
AND CHARINDEX('-',Account) > 0
```

UPDATE:

Added in a check for no hyphen scenarios so you don't undate for no reason.  That said, I would recommend going with @Richards solution.  It's much prettier.

Comment: @Abe - `LEN(SUBSTRING(Account, CHARINDEX('-',Account)+1,LEN(Account)) ) > 2` returns {true} when there is no hyphen

Comment: @Abe since you're testing it, OP wants to KEEP 2 chars after dash, not remove it all. You're doing better than me with +2

Comment: I threw you a +1.  People are probably just trying to throttle down your ridiculous rep gain...  10k in a month?!

Comment: @cloud @abe - STUFF has been around from 2000 or even earlier.. There is nothing `2005+` about it!

Comment: Really?  I went to MSDN and they only had 2005,2008 and Denali for the documentation

Comment: But according to think link: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1026 it appears to be available in 2000.  Good to know!

Comment: @Abe - The doco for 2005 to Denali is done in a new style, 2005 is included in the "version dropdown" since it is still "current".  The old style docs for 2000 is still around if you hunt for it, I believe STUFF was introduced by Sybase so it would have been around even in SQL 6.5

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) if you are using SQL Server 2005 or greater.

```
WITH CTE
AS
    (
    SELECT Account 
        , CHARINDEX('-', Account) AS [Dash Index]
        , CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('-', Account)+2 > 2
                THEN CHARINDEX('-', Account)+2
            ELSE LEN(Account)
          END AS [Acceptable Length]
        , LEN(Account) AS [Total Length]
    FROM Documents
    )
UPDATE CTE
SET Account = SUBSTRING(Account, 1, [Acceptable Length])
WHERE [Total Length] <> [Acceptable Length]
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I'd be curious to see how the performance compares between this and mine.

Comment: Is it just a matter of changing `SUBSTRING(Account, CHARINDEX('-', Account)+1)` to `SUBSTRING(Account, CHARINDEX('-', Account)+1, 1000)`?

Comment: @Sean - No.. haha.. For '16589553-12346' it returns '12346'. Either one of us is not reading the question correctly.

Comment: You want to start at the beginning of the string, not after the dash.

Comment: @Richard, @Abe -- *Smacks head* Should be fixed ... thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sean I was almost compelled to give you +1 once you fixed it, except given '16589553' it ends up with '16' ...

Comment: @Richard -- *Laughs* You're making me work for it ... updated to allow for non-dashed values.

Comment: +1 for sticking in there for a question that has been ostensibly answered

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Documents
SET Account = STUFF(Account, CharIndex('-', Account)+3, 1000, '')
where SubmissionID=45925 AND Account like '%-___%'
```

Comment: @Abe It needs to have a hyphen and more than 2, otherwise we won't be working on it. Ending % is to pick out trail of any length

Comment: Ahh, you're right, I was thinking it needed to be the other way around for some reason.

Comment: @Abe,@Richard thank you both for your suggestions I will try both methods.